# What is a quick way to force CRLF in C# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, string, newline

How would you normalize all new-line sequences in a string to one type?

I'm looking to make them all CRLF for the purpose of email (MIME documents).  Ideally this would be wrapped in a static method, executing very quickly, and not using regular expressions (since the variances of line breaks, carriage returns, etc. are limited).  Perhaps there's even a BCL method I've overlooked?

ASSUMPTION: After giving this a bit more thought, I think it's a safe assumption to say that CR's are either stand-alone or part of the CRLF sequence.  That is, if you see CRLF then you know all CR's can be removed.  Otherwise it's difficult to tell how many lines should come out of something like "\r\n\n\r".

Comment: The best solution is `myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, "(?<!\r)\n", "\r\n")`, which converts all `LF` to `CRLF`. See explanation of the regex here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32704/968003

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
input.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "\r\n")
```

This will work if the input contains only one type of line breaks - either CR, or LF, or CR+LF.

Comment: Also works for displaying unknown text on an HTML page by using the last replace to insert a BR tag.

Server.HtmlEncode(input).Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "<br />");

Comment: This seams to fix the issues with T4 templates.   I kept getting crazy returns in my generated output.

Answer (score 33):

It depends on *exactly* what the requirements are. In particular, how do you want to handle "\r" on its own? Should that count as a line break or not? As an example, how should "a\n\rb" be treated? Is that one very odd line break, one "\n" break and then a rogue "\r", or two separate linebreaks? If "\r" and "\n" can both be linebreaks on their own, why should "\r\n" not be treated as two linebreaks?

Here's some code which I suspect is *reasonably* efficient.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class LineBreaks
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        Test("a\nb");
        Test("a\nb\r\nc");
        Test("a\r\nb\r\nc");
        Test("a\rb\nc");
        Test("a\r");
        Test("a\n");
        Test("a\r\n");
    }

    static void Test(string input)
    {
        string normalized = NormalizeLineBreaks(input);
        string debug = normalized.Replace("\r", "\\r")
                                 .Replace("\n", "\\n");
        Console.WriteLine(debug);
    }

    static string NormalizeLineBreaks(string input)
    {
        // Allow 10% as a rough guess of how much the string may grow.
        // If we're wrong we'll either waste space or have extra copies -
        // it will still work
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder((int) (input.Length * 1.1));

        bool lastWasCR = false;

        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (lastWasCR)
            {
                lastWasCR = false;
                if (c == '\n')
                {
                    continue; // Already written \r\n
                }
            }
            switch (c)
            {
                case '\r':
                    builder.Append("\r\n");
                    lastWasCR = true;
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    builder.Append("\r\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    builder.Append(c);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool; this would definitely be useful on more arbitrary input!  For my case I chose to go with an assumption (made an edit), but I voted this up regardless.

Comment: Right. If performance is really significant you may want to benchmark this solution against the accepted one - but only if you've actually ascertained that it's significant via a profiler! I would *hope* this is faster, as it only needs to make a single pass through the data.

Comment: What is about using RegExpr ? not good performance ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140926/normalize-newlines-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Kiquenet: Yes, that's another alternative.

Comment: I was just about to write this code when I stumbled on this. Works exactly how I want. Thanks!

Comment: Kudos for including tests.

Comment: @LosManos: That's "tests" in heavy airquotes, given that they just write to the console ;) But yes, better than nothing!

Comment: @JonSkeet Those "tests" are easy to read and easy to copy into an editor or IDE and experiment. No need for x-u-ms-test and whatnot. Just as we (i.e. me) want them on SO.

Comment: @LosManos: We are very much of the same mind on that front :)

Answer (score 9):

Simple variant:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\r\n|\r|\n", "\r\n")
```

For better performance:

```
static Regex newline_pattern = new Regex(@"\r\n|\r|\n", RegexOptions.Compiled);
[...]
    newline_pattern.Replace(input, "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string nonNormalized = "\r\n\n\r";

string normalized = nonNormalized.Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Comment: This example produces four line breaks, whereas the nonNormalized string contains two.

Comment: True, it brings up a good question as to when a sequence is used and when it is merely removed (ignored).

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick way to do that, I mean.

It does not use an expensive regex function.
It also does not use multiple replacement functions that each individually did loop over the data with several checks, allocations, etc.

So the search is done directly in one `for` loop. For the number of times that the capacity of the result array has to be increased, a loop is also used within the `Array.Copy` function. That are all the loops.
In some cases, a larger page size might be more efficient.

```
public static string NormalizeNewLine(this string val)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        return val;

    const int page = 6;
    int a = page;
    int j = 0;
    int len = val.Length;
    char[] res = new char[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char ch = val[i];

        if (ch == '\r')
        {
            int ni = i + 1;
            if (ni < len && val[ni] == '\n')
            {
                res[j++] = '\r';
                res[j++] = '\n';
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (a == page) // Ensure capacity
                {
                    char[] nres = new char[res.Length + page];
                    Array.Copy(res, 0, nres, 0, res.Length);
                    res = nres;
                    a = 0;
                }

                res[j++] = '\r';
                res[j++] = '\n';
                a++;
            }
        }
        else if (ch == '\n')
        {
            int ni = i + 1;
            if (ni < len && val[ni] == '\r')
            {
                res[j++] = '\r';
                res[j++] = '\n';
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (a == page) // Ensure capacity
                {
                    char[] nres = new char[res.Length + page];
                    Array.Copy(res, 0, nres, 0, res.Length);
                    res = nres;
                    a = 0;
                }

                res[j++] = '\r';
                res[j++] = '\n';
                a++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            res[j++] = ch;
        }
    }

    return new string(res, 0, j);
}
```

I now that '\n\r' is not actually used on basic platforms. But who would use two types of linebreaks in succession to indicate two linebreaks?

If you want to know that, then you need to take a look before to know if the \n and \r both are used separately in the same document.

Comment: It's unreadable, I doubt the performance gain makes up for it.

Comment: The code is based on the stringbuilder Replace function. Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs

Comment: Why did you rollback the edit? There's no need for more spaces

Comment: It depends on the size of the string as to how performant it would be. All of the other answers using String.Replace() produce multiple strings, which could potentially be huge, and do multiple passes.

Answer (score 1):

Environment.NewLine;

A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Converts both types of line breaks (`\n` and `\n\r`'s) into CRLFs

on .NET 6 it's 35% faster than regex (Benchmarked using BenchmarkDotNet)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the technique as described in the accepted answer:

```
input.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "\r\n")
```

But recently I discovered the existence of a dotnet core function called ReplaceLineEndings.  And looking at the source it uses ReadOnlySpan.  In my case I am dealing with email messages.  So for SMTP transport I must end all lines with crlf.  My messages can be quite large.  I expected using the ReplaceLineEndings method would significantly reduce allocation.

example: `mimeMessage.ReplaceLineEndings("\r\n")`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replacelineendings?view=net-6.0

But then, I was like wait a minute.  The Replace function is probably optimized also.  And of course it is.  So I ran a simple `Benchmarkdotnet` test with a very small email message.

```cs
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[Config(typeof(Config))]
public class StringReplaceCompare
{
    private string _mimeMessage;
    private class Config : ManualConfig
    {
        public Config()
        {
            AddColumn(
                StatisticColumn.P95
            );
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string StringReplace() =>
        _mimeMessage.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "\r\n");

    [Benchmark]
    public string StringReplaceLineEndings() =>
        _mimeMessage.ReplaceLineEndings("\r\n");


    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mimeMessage = @"From: <joe@Machine1.Lab>
To: joe@Machine2.lab
Subject: Simple Text Message
Date: Wed, 1 Oct 2023 14:53:27 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Message-Id: 12345
Sender: joe@achine1.Lab

Yo. Wassup?".Replace("\r\n", "n");

    }
}
```

```
| Method                   | Mean      | Error     | StdDev    | P95       | Allocated |
|------------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| StringReplace            |  69.09 ns |  3.131 ns |  9.231 ns |  84.91 ns |         - |
| StringReplaceLineEndings | 590.70 ns | 14.439 ns | 42.347 ns | 663.81 ns |         - |
```

For my use case of transporting mime messages over SMTP the accepted answer is the best fit.