# C# reading a text line by line, where line delimiter is a custom

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of bytes (say byte[] data), which contains text with custom line delimiters, for example: "\r\n" (CRLF "\x0D\x0A"), "\r", "\n", "\x0D\x0A\x0D" or even "@".

At the moment I'm going to use the following solution:

1. Normalize line breaks to CRLF (here is an example how to normalize CRLF [What is a quick way to force CRLF in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841396/what-is-a-quick-way-to-force-crlf-in-c-net))
2. Use StringReader to read text line by line

   ```
   using (String Reader sr = new StringReader(data.ToString()))
   {
       string line;
       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           // Process the line 
       }
   }
   ```

I'm using C#, .NET 3.5.
Is there any better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You should normalize your line endings to `\n`, which only takes 2 replacements instead of 3. Notice in your link that the answer first normalizes to `\n` and only after that changes `\n` to `\r\n`.

Comment: Yup, It turns out that I need to notmalize line endings to either of the following: "\r", "\n", "\r\n"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline.aspx

A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed. The returned value is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the end of the underlying string has been reached.

Comment: For fastest performance, you could split it by hand ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option to limit calls to `string.Replace` to just the multi-character delimiters.

```
private static readonly char[] DelimiterChars = { '\r', '\n', '@' };
private static readonly string[] DelimiterStrings = { "\r\n\r", "\r\n" };
```

Then later...

```
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
foreach (string delim in DelimiterStrings)
    text = text.Replace(delim, "\n");

foreach (string line in text.Split(DelimiterChars))
{
    // processing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp instead, which will give you much more flexibility.