# Carriage return (/r) missing when encoding and decoding a string using c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, carriage-return

I have the following string :

```
This is the string to
test carriage return
using c#
```

The above string has two carriage returns in the end of lines. I have to encode this string to pass to a WCF service and then decode the string for further process.

```
//TO ENCODE
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rawstring);
            string encodedStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);


//TO DECODE
            byte[] rawUtf8EncodedData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(encodedstring);
            string decodedStr =  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawUtf8EncodedData);
```

After Encoding I get the below string :

```
This is the string to\ntest carriage return\nusing c#
```

After Decoding I get the below string :

```
This is the string to\ntest carriage return\nusing c#
```

Problem is, I need the carriage return back for some reason and not the \n in my string after decoding. How can I achieve this ? The above string is only for illustration and in actual string, there would be lots of carriage returns and symbols

Comment: If you are viewing the strings in the debugger, it will show you `\n` instead of a carriage return. Try outputting the string to the console or a log file and see if the carriage returns are there.

Comment: I am using this string to do some logic, which will fail if \n is there. It requires a carriage return to work. And right now it fails, because \n is present in the raw string.

Comment: Where do you *"have the following string"*? Line ends can be encoded in a variety of ways

Comment: Just tested (to be sure). Inserting `\r\n` or `\r` or `\n`, all are returned as the original. What do you mean with  *[the] string has two carriage returns*? Are you extracting this string from a `RichTextBox`, maybe?.

Comment: @DStanley `\n` is not a carriage return. It is a line feed. `\r` is a carriage return.

Comment: `The above string has two carriage returns in the end of lines` The short answer is that your original string does **not** have a carriage return in it. Where is the original string coming from? Is it a C# program? Somewhere else? What OS is it coming from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a quick way to force CRLF in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841396/what-is-a-quick-way-to-force-crlf-in-c-sharp-net)

Comment: What .Net is this running on?

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rawstring);
string encodedStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

The first line gets bytes using the Default encoding. On .Net Core it's UTF-8 and you're likely okay, but on Windows it's the system code page from the OS, which could be *anything*.

The second line of code then treats those bytes as if they are already in UTF-8 format, regardless of you what you actually got. This might work for a lot of strings, but eventually it's gonna fail spectacularly. Morever, the result is still a .Net string, which is the Unicode (UTF-16) encoding internally... so what you end up with is still UTF-16, *not UTF-8*.

If you need to send a UTF-8 string to a network service, get the UTF-8 bytes using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`, and send the bytes as if they were a string.

Comment: Definitely. This *conversion* will not fail for a very limited sub-set of characters. Depending on the Local Encoding, possibly none. Outside these limited CodePoints, you get *garbage*.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing \n with \r\n works fine